# Accessing back and forth screens through bash script

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

I have created multiple `screen` to run the same piece of code with different parameters. The way I'm doing it right now is manually attaching one screen, pass the command and arguments and then `Ctrl a+d` to detach that screen. Then again attaching a different screen and again passing the arguments and detaching from that screen. Is it possible to write a bash script to do this whole process automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating multiple `screen` sessions is probably not the best option. Screen supports the notion of putting multiple windows within one session, which makes collections like that easier to handle. There's `^A 1`, `^A 2` etc. `^A '` and `^A "` to switch between the windows and `^A w` to list them.

Going with one screen session, you can start a session and then the commands inside with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -d -m -S test
screen -S test -X screen -t title somecommand someargs...
screen -S test -X screen -t othertitle somecommand otherargs
```

`screen -d -m` starts a new detached session, `-S` gives the session a name or refers to one by name. `-X` sends the rest of the command line as a command to a running session, and the `screen` command (within `screen`) opens a new window and runs a command there. `-t` can be used with `screen` to give the *window* a title.

Or, you could put the commands for `screen` in a file and then use `:source` to run the file (similar to `.screenrc`). See the manual for some examples and a reference on the commands `screen` supports. (There are a truckload.)